Which type of UML illustrates *static* threading aspects of a multi threaded application?
Im searching for the best suited UML diagram for illustration of the following static aspects of a multi threaded application:

show the threads in the application; potentially grouped for threads belonging to certain "classes" like e.g. worker threads
information on priorities (priority values or relations)
means of communication and synchronization between threads (e.g. message queue) and their roles

The "collaboration" diagram comes close, but I am not really happy with that choice. For instance, communication seems to focus on the type of data exchanged and sequences of these exchanges (which in my opinion is more a dynamic aspect).
Which alternative would you recommend? Or should I rethink my understanding of collaboration diagrams?

I guess you just need a good mix. But: what is static threading??

@qwerty_so I was refering to static aspects. Even if threading has many dynamic aspects, part of the architecture of a multithreaded application has static nature (like how two threads communicate with each other; most of the time, you probably wouldn't want to change this dynamically).

The U in UML might stand for universal, but that doesn't mean everything can in fact be modelled by it.

@PeteKirkham and the L is fo Language. So different languages need different skill to express ideas. and different languages use different approaches. Even more some hvr words you can not express in another language.

You could use an object diagram like this:


There are multiple ways to represent threads and concurrency in UML. It is not fully clear what you mean with static however, since concurrency expresses in behavior and behavior is dynamic.
If you mean "structural", it could be in class diagrams or in deployment diagrams. If you lean for a given configuration/number of threads, it could be deployement diagrams, activity diagrams, object diagrams as mentioned by the admiral or sequence diagrams. Here some more details:

a class diagram can show active classes that run in their own thread. You may have several such active classes corresponding to different kind of active classes. However, this view is structural. It will not help you if you have on'y one kind of active classes, or if your multithreading is not rooted in active classes.
sequence diagrams are very good at showing instances of active classes communicating between them. In this case, each lifeline corresponds to an instance of an active class. However, the focus is really on the detail of the interactions. The challenge comes when you need to also show interactions with non-active classes, which makes it difficult to follow the threading, especially if par combined fragments are used.
communication diagrams are the siblings of sequence diagrams. They have the same semantic but the notation is different. If you need to mix instances of active and non-active classes, you might be lost with communication diagrams.
activity diagrams are best at showing the big picture of parallelism, with forks and joins, and the object flows can use implicit or explicit buffers to represent queues. See for example this other answer on Software Engineering Stackexchange
state machine diagrams offer similar fetures, but in my view there are more ambiguous regarding multithreading.
last but not least, deployment diagrams can detail the distribution of components / component instances across different processing nodes / processing environments, and communication channels between those components or these environments. It's excellent if you want for example to depict a given configuration, with x threads on y servers running different components.

Priorities and the like can be managed either dynamically through properties of active obects, or more statically, for exemple using tagged values for stereotypes, in the model itself. The value tags could then be specified the different diagrams.
So it all depends on the focus you want to give on this. Here a more general answer also referring to an OMG article.
